# PS Framework - Can't to import datas

Tags: import, module, frameworks, prestashop

I'm new in the prestashop's world.

I recently installed the version 1.7.3.0 and 1.7.2.5 and tried to install a template, but when I imported the template I have to import some datas with the PS Framework. And that's the problem, I can't import files.

I tried to do it but when I click on the button to upload, I have a message on the right that tell me that was a success but nothing is displayed as the videos that I could see and nothing happens next. The PSFramework page have to load the different themes (several version / form of the template).

I'm using windows 10 and is therefore tried with prestashop 1.7.2.5 and 1.7.3.0.

If you could help me find a solution it will be amazing!

Thank's a lot !

PS: Sorry for my bad english ^^

Comment: How does your question relate to coding?  Would this be better suited to the superuser exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Cpanel -> Select PHP Version-> Switch` to `PHP` options you have several variables that can be changed.
We have modified `max_filesize` to `16 mb`